# Unable to use order by in sub query in HQL

Tags: sql-order-by, subquery, hql

I have this HQL where I need a subquery. I know it's not legal to make a subquery in order by, but I can't figure out how to do it

```
SELECT OBJECT(l) FROM InboundNotification l 
 INNER JOIN l.item item 
 WHERE l.job = ? ORDER BY (SELECT SUM(itemInst.qty) 
 FROM ItemInst itemInst 
  WHERE itemInst.receivedFromNotification_id = l.id) DESC, item.localId DESC
```

The above fails since I have the subquery in order by. How can I reconfigure it so this will work?

A sort in the Java code is not a option here even though it's almost as efficient.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i haven't a notion of hql, but I'm gonna assume it's something like other query languages dive in here given that this question has remained unanswered for so long.

could you rewrite the query so it's something like this:

```
SELECT OBJECT(l), SUM(itemInst.qty) theSum
FROM InboundNotification l
INNER JOIN l.item item WHERE l.job = ?
INNER JOIN ItemInst on ItemInst.KEY = l.KEY
WHERE itemInst.receivedFromNotification_id = l.id)
GROUP BY OBJECT(l)
ORDER BY theSum
```

where `ItemInst.KEY = l.KEY` shows the appropriate relationship for your situation (if such a relationship exists)